# Circular Queue using arrays with no count approach. (java)

Tags: java

I've implemented it successfully with count, the book I'm using to learn just shows the code but without any proper explanation.

I've tried doing some search on google but can't find a material explaining it.

All what I've understood that Front and Rear points will assume the same location if the array is empty or full, so we are using an extra slot in the array "to do some sort of checking I don't understand to get it done".

Does anybody have a tutorial on this? I'm sorry if this comes as waiting for someone to feed me information, but I truly cannot find anything.

Comment: It is hard to tell from your question what you are having problems with. I guess the trick is to always leave at least one element empty in order to distinguish the cases of completely empty and completely full.

Comment: Yup, this is what I get, but how would I actually implement the methods? Like isEmpty(), isFull(), and getSize()? How is the extra slot actually used in the program?

Answer (score 1):

The math is pretty simple: if you have the beginning and the ending indexes, you can have three situations there:

- The ending index is lower,
- The beginning index is lower, and
- The indexes are the same.

When the ending index is lower, say, b=10 and e=3, all the data is located between the two indexes. You can compute the count by subtracting the ending index from the beginning index, b-e: in my example, you've got seven items in the queue.

When the beginning index is lower, say, b=3 and e=10, then the data goes around the end of the queue. Say, the total size of your queue is N=100. Then the number of data items is b+N-e, or 3+100-10=93 elements.

The fact that you would be able to use at most N-1 elements follows from these two formulas: the highest number of entries that you can have is N-1 for both formulas, because the situation when all N entries are filled up is indistinguishable from the situation when the queue is empty.

You can check if your queue is full by comparing `(b+1)%N` to `e`. If they are the same, you cannot put any more data into your queue.